# Where is the `Drush` command specific documentation?

Tags: drush, configuration

To be more specific than the title, I want to know what `drush cim` exactly does, like:

- where is the `drush cim` command specific documentation?
- Does `cim` command remove the files after they are imported, or not?
- where are the setting files imported from, can you provide me with a path relative to the root (I mean, relative to where the main `index.php` file of `drupal` is)?
- can we change the import path?
- can we tell `drush` to just delete any (previously exported) setting files ?

Comment: We don’t locate documentation here (it’s something that many years have taught us that Q+A is not a good format for). But that said, it seems you’ve already found the documentation, you just don’t personally find it useful - that doesn’t automatically mean that more detailed documentation exists somewhere else. In this case I doubt it does. So that probably leaves you with 2 options: 1. raise a feature request to drush for more detailed documentation, or 2. ask a detailed question here about the specific, practical problem you’re trying to solve by using `cim`, and how far you’ve got with it

Comment: Look at step 4 of method 3 in this post - it may answer some questions: https://www.morpht.com/blog/drupal-and-composer-part-3-converting-management-existing-drupal-8-site-composer

Comment: Look at https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/blob/9.7.1/src/Drupal/Commands/config/ConfigImportCommands.php#L150-L264 to find the exact code that's being executed.

Comment: Please don't change questions once they've been answered, as existing submissions will be invalidated by this. If you have a new question, please ask separately. Thanks!

Comment: The gripe doesn't need to be in the question as it offers nothing.

Comment: Mitigating personal feelings is not the purpose of an Q&A site nor is it helpful.

Comment: @Kevin Just leave the useful performance compare alone (which's the question's background too).

Comment: Hey Top-Master, precision is always appreciated among developers but could you please stop editing your question into something completely new? If you found out you needed something different than what's asked originally, simply ask a new question. You can then even add and accept your own answer to it. 

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> where is the drush cim command specific documentation?

https://drushcommands.com/drush-9x/config/config:import/

> Does cim command remove the files after they are imported

No.

> where are the setting files imported from, can you provide me with a
>   path relative to the root (I mean, relative to where the main
>   `index.php` file of `drupal` is)?

The path to the configuration folder is set in `settings.php` file. It will look like `$configuration_directories = "path/to/config/folder"`. This is relative to the `Drupal` root directory.

> can we change the import path?

Yes, you can change the path in the `settings.php` file.

> can we tell `drush` to just delete any (previously exported) setting files ?

Anytime you export configuration, all the old configuration files will be wiped out, and new ones created from the current active configuration in the database.

Comment: does running `drush cdel` delete all (previously exported) configurations?

Comment: No. That function requires an argument - the configuration object to be deleted. I don’t believe all config can be deleted with that function.

Comment: Also note that ‘cdel’ deletes configuration from the active configuration in the database, not the exported .yml files.

Comment: I would like to delete my quesion, but to be able to do that, you need to delete your answer first. Thanks in advance. (I am sure with 14K points you don't mind losing few here)